# Rename a subsection

Tags: beamer

I'm using Beamer with Warsaw theme. A frame has 4 spaces (2 on the top, 2 on the bottom) dedicated to some names. The upper-left gives the section names and the upper-right all the subsection names.

What I'd like is to have only the active subsection name (and not the others ones) or a name I would give to a variable.

For example, to have only the subsection 1's name when I'm in subsection 1 and so on for the others subsection.

I've tried to change subsecname (`\newcommand\subsecname{a_title}`) or to create a variable which I could change `\def\myname{a_title}`, `\subsection{\myname}` and changing `myname`) but this doesn't work.

Would someone have a solution ?

---

(copied from the non-answer)

The theme I use is not Warsaw but Malmoe.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper,handout]{beamer}
\input{../header.tex}
\title{Title\hspace{4cm}\hfill\insertframenumber\null}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item this is a frame 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item this is another frame 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item this is another frame
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like is that "Subsection 1" appears only at for this subsection and "Subsection 2" for the another subsection (only one line each time).

The file header.tex contains some commands for loading package.

Comment: Welcome. Do you mind adding a minimal working example (MWE)? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. That way users can try to answer their question without having to come up with their own examples.

Comment: @Pascal017 Please, add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like another theme would better fit your needs. I suggest `Copenhagen` or you could combine the `infolines` outer theme with the colour theme from `Malmoe`:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper,handout]{beamer}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=structure}

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank  you very much. That's what I wanted : Another question : do you know how to remove the bottom right space (where the date is) ? Once again, thank you.

Comment: @Pascal017 To remove the date: `\date[]{\today}`. I would not remove the complete space, as this already displays the frame number without your hack to use `\hspace{4cm}\hfill\insertframenumber\null`, which will cause problems with the pdf meta data and/or if you want to add a title page.

Comment: Yes. perhaps I should look also at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320776/remove-the-slide-count-from-beamer-footer and try to create a new outer theme. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @Pascal017 If you can make clear specifications of how the new footline should look like (including colours), feels free to ask a new question.

Comment: @Pascal017 and please delete you non-answer.

Comment: Thanks. The non-answer should be deleted. Everything is OK now. I just had to get the file beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty to rename it and to modify it to create a new package. In fact, I didn't know that outer themes existed (so also infolines) and how it worked.